# DEVEXPRESS How can I pass multiple values in a report parameter to a query param?

Tags: webforms, devexpress, parameters, xtrareport

I created a parameter `IdWorker` in the report, and in the parameter properties I have assigned these default values: `'w00012', 'w00013', 'w00014'` and I created the parameter as a string. If I add only one value then it works, but the problem is when I want to add more than one value :

[image]

I also created a query with a parameter `paramIdWorker`:

[image]

[image]

When I add only one value the query works correctly, but when I add more values the query returns no results.  How can I add multiple values to a parameter?
I accept suggestions thanks.